# How to integrate $\cos(\theta)\exp(i a \sin(\theta-\phi))$

Tags: calculus

How can I integrate the following:

$$
\cos\left(\theta\right)\exp(ia\sin(\theta-\phi))
$$

Comment: What variable are you integrating with respect to? Theta or phi?

Comment: Do you mean $$\cos\left(\theta\right)\exp(ia)\sin(\theta-\phi)$$ ?

Comment: No. the expression is correctly given. I want to integrate w.r.t \theta

Comment: Check with a table of Bessel functions.